# Help with this JET Sql Query 

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, jet

I need help to do this query select.

for example I have these fields:

- idInvoice
- date
- amount

Depending of the **date** I need multiply the field "**amount**" for x number or other one.

For example, if the **date** is less 01/01/2010 to multiply for 20 . But if it is major or equal to multiply for 35

```
Select idInvoice, date, amount, amount * varNumber from invoices
```

Comment: SOLVED: IS POSSIBLE DOING "UNION"

Comment: It is considered acceptable to answer your own question. If you've solved the problem, you might consider submitting your solution as an answer.

Comment: but how i can submit my solution as answer? only I can edit title.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date field does not allow Nulls, you should be able to use an IIf expression for your calculation.

```
SELECT
    idInvoice,
    [date],
    amount,
    IIf([date] < #2010/01/01#, amount * 20, amount * 30) AS extended_amount
FROM invoices;
```

Notice I enclosed the date field name in square brackets because date is a reserved word in Access.  The square brackets signal the database engine that you want a field named "date" rather than the Date() function.

Also Access date fields include a time component.  So that query will multiple amount by 20 for any values earlier than midnight at the start of this year.  That means for 1/1/2010 at 1:00 AM, amount would be multiplied by 30.  If that isn't what you want, change the IIf expression.

And if your [date] field allows Nulls, look at Access' help for the Nz() function.

Answer (score 1):

or

```
SELECT 
    idInvoice, 
    [date], 
    amount, 
    amount *IIf([date] < #2010/01/01#, 20, 30) AS extended_amount 
FROM invoices;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select idInvoice, date, amount, 
amount * case when date<'20100101' then 20 else 35 end as amount from invoices
```

Comment: i am using access from .net (jet sql). And if runs "CASE" display syntax error

Comment: Jet/ACE has not CASE statement in SQL.